# The problem of detecting when a page closes Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that I am trying to solve.
For example, I have a script made to collect data.
I would like when I close the page (I do not change the link) to detect this and cancel everything in localestorage. (I don't use sessionStorage because it would generate a new session if I open blank and I don't need that)

For example, I use this event to retrieve the time on the page

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
        const end = new Date().getTime();
        const totalTime = (end - start) / 1000;

        localStorage.setItem("time_spent_on_page", totalTime);
});
window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("time_spent_on_page");
      });
```

But I could use the same bien to detect when the page closes, but it doesn't really work that way.
How could I detect exactly that I change a page and when can I detect if I close it?
Are there any such events?

Comment: what's the point of setting localstorage on `beforeunload`, just to remove localstorage right after on `unload`?

Comment: I would like to delete the data from localStorage when I close the page

Comment: you should do that on `beforeunload`

Comment: Yes, but that event also works if you refresh the page :)
I would like to detect if the page is closed (exit)

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Beware this is a very complex area, moreover now that [BFCache](https://web.dev/bfcache/) is a thing almost everywhere. Even when your page has been navigated away it's not necessarily entirely "dead" yet. It's generally easier to handle it from the other end: at page load you check if you're coming from a page refresh, history nav' or from blank.

Comment: So the goal is next.

When I move from one page to another, that spent_time should not be deleted
But when I close the page (close the page) let it close

Comment: Then, why can't you discard the value stored when you load the page from blank, and only look at it when reloading or when coming from your website?